# how to remove shadow below actionbar with AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I tried to remove the shadow below the toolbar with the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar, using every recommendation of people who have ever answer it before, but no one worked. I tried

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

and

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/solid_line</item> ....

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/accueil_color" />
<size android:height="15dp" />
</shape>
```

and with this,

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

the shadow goes from the top of the screen but not disapear.

Have you any idea for totally remove this shadow line ??

Answer (score 81):

I'm not an expert but I run into the same problem just a few hours ago. So the idea here is that with `AppCompat` we have to manage the library attributes rather than Android attributes. In other words, instead of android:elevation try app:elevation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

I just tried another option without `AppBarLayout`. This way works perfectly fine for me, the shadow is completely gone. So I suspect the problem is in your other View. I don't think it's your `ToolBar` drops the shadow.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:elevation="0dp" />
```

Comment: Hum my xml is like this, i don't have android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout, just the toolbar widget,

Comment: Can't comment on your answer due to lack of karma ). My best guess is your first view drops the shadow, not the toolbar.

Comment: Arf ...
I have tried to change elevation in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, and that change the location of the shadow, i think it is not the cause ... :/

Sorry That has worked :D thinks

How to make resolved ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the last comment... What about removing this entire attribute - android:elevation="@dimen/statusBarElevation" ?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I had put
        android:elevation="0dp" 
in
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
and that dismissed the shadow line :D.

Comment: One thing to be careful of: if you use `AppBarLayout` in conjunction with `CoordinatorLayout` and you set elevation to zero, it will be placed behind the "main content" in the `CoordinatorLayout` (since the main content likely has a zero elevation too) .. effectively hiding the Toolbar entirely.

Answer (score 74):

use `app:elevation="0dp" instead of android:elevation`

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem. Applying `app:elevation="0dp"` on `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` solves the issue

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Add `app:elevation="0dp"` in AppBarLayout and shadow will be hide.

Comment: dont forget findViewById(R.id.appBar).bringToFront();   https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931318/2736039

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

If your Toolbar is inside `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`
Adding app:elevation="0dp" on `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`will solve your problem.

Else add `app:elevation="0dp"` on `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:elevation="0dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6):

Just use after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
{
   getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

Just put your `AppBarLayout` inside of a `LinearLayout` on a separated XML file, and then, include this XML to your main XML.

Answer (score 1):

***@DmitryO***
Hum my xml is like this, i don't have `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`, just the toolbar widget,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeAccueil">

    <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/statusBarHeight"
        android:background="@color/accueil_colorDark"
        android:elevation="@dimen/statusBarElevation"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarAccueil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        materialdesign:elevation="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Have I to had this ? (I think this will not change the result)

Answer (score 0):

If your are not using Toolbar on the Layout and you have the default toolbar from `AppCompactActivity`  this can help you

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

At least it worked for me.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, use:

```
supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0.0f
```

Regards!