# How I can remove shadow or divider from bottom of AppBar layout or Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

[image]

I wants to remove shadow or divider from bottom of AppBar layout or Toolbar

Here is my xml code

elevation, actionBarDivider already tried.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527721/how-to-set-the-elevation-of-appbarlayout-to-0/34527789

Comment: @AslamHossin Please check as mentioned and show in code I already tried this solution.

Comment: android:elevation="0dp" will be replaced with app:elevation="0dp"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set elevation 0(Zero) dp (ex: android:elevation="0dp" or app:elevation="0dp"), like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                 />

 </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Try app:elevation="0dp" instead of android:elevation="0d" in the AppBarLayout also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `app:elevation="0dp"` also hiding the **Toolbar** layout, so I've used `android:outlineProvider="none"` in **AppBarLayout** and it works fine.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <!-- Your Layout -->
    
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```